# Using 'too', 'also', 'either', 'neither' in negative sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

Suppose my friend says "I don't like tea" and I feel the same. Then which ones of the following would be correct?

1. I don't like tea too.
2. I also don't like tea.
3. I don't like tea either.
4. I don't like tea neither.
5. Me too.( Shortcut reply)

(I know that I can say " Neither do I" but I just wanna know for these particular sentences)

Comment: I would consider (3) to be the only entirely correct one. Instead of (5) you might say _Me neither_ (I've learned from these forums that some people say _Me either_).

Comment: Can I say " Nor do I "?

Comment: Would using "me too" be incorrect?

Comment: You can say _neither do I_ or _nor do I. Me too_ means you agree with a positive statement (your friend likes tea and so do you).

Comment: @KateBunting I also don't like tea. is fine but it has two meanings. I myself don't like it (another  person has spoken before to say that) and You don't like A, B and C. And "I also don't like tea". Don't you agree with those?

Comment: @Lambie - I find _I also don't like tea_ much less natural than _I don't like tea either_.  I would find it more acceptable as _I also dislike tea_ - it's the combination of _also_ with a negative that jars.

Comment: @KateBunting If you are listing what you don't like, I also don't like tea. could be added as an afterthought to the list...

Answer (score 1):

#1 is incorrect. We cannot use **too** with **don't.**

#2 might technically be correct, but it sounds a bit formal somehow—or maybe just weird. I don't know anyone who speaks this way in any situation. And changing the sequence absolutely makes it incorrect: **I don't like tea also** does not work at all. So I'm hesitant to call your version correct.

#3 is the best, most natural way to communicate the idea. It will work in formal and casual situations alike.

#4 is incorrect in most dialects, including the standard dialect. Matching **neither** with **don't** creates an inappropriate double negative.

#5 is incorrect for the same reason #1 is incorrect. In its place you can substitute **Me either** or **Me neither.** Both of these are quite casual.